# How to render flat list horizontally and vertically?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a 10x10 matrix and I want to render it in a flat list. How can I enable vertical and horizontal scrolling on this so that user can select the item of their choice out of 10X10 matrix. I just want my flat list to be scrolled in both the ways.

Comment: share your code and screenshot of your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please pass this in flatlist **numColumns={10}**  according to number of columns you want to show , it will display items horizontally in a flatlist
in a grid format 
(You don't need separate scrollview)

Comment: Thanx buddy. You save a lot of Time. Once again Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
        data={data}
        numColumns={4}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View
            style={{
              padding: 20,
            }}
          >
            <Image
              source={{
                uri: item.uri,
              }}
              style={{ width: 64, height: 50 }}
            />
            <Txt.$Title
              style={{ fontSize: 10, paddingTop: 5, textAlign: "center" }}
            >
              {tr(item.name)}
            </Txt.$Title>
          </View>
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={Kitten.Divider_________}
        ListEmptyComponent={
          <Txt.Indicator marginV>{tr("No trophy found")}</Txt.Indicator>
        }
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

For this, you can nest your `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` as follow

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>
     <FlatList />
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

To achieve the both direction Scroll behaviour, you can do that by nesting a second `ScrollView` like this

```
<ScrollView
 horizontal
 bounces={false}
>
  <ScrollView
    nestedScrollEnabled
    bounces={false}
    contentContainerStyle={{ height: //the height of your inner content }}
   >
      <View>
        <FlatList />
      </View>
   </ScrollView>
 </ScrollView>
```

I haven't tested this yet, so please make sure to ask me anything.

Comment: isn't it bad practice to include Flatlist inside a scrollview?

Comment: Yes, you will get a warning from react-native using this and it could/will cause problems